# Multiple forms inside a foreach

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have a `foreach` that show many forms with the same action ending with diferente id's.
But, the tag `<form>` just appears in the first form. All others, the fields appears, but don't the `<form>`
I tried to put the `id` for the form different in the loop. But doesn't work.

The code:

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
                'url' => array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => 'aprovar', $procuracao['Attorney']['id']), 'id' => $procuracao['Attorney']['id']
                )); ?>
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Alçada:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input ('alcada', array('type' => 'select', 'label' => FALSE, 'options' => array(
                                                                                 'Até 10.000' =>  'Até 10.000',
                                                                                 'Até 50.000' => 'Até 50.000',
                                                                                 'Acima de 100.000' => 'Acima de 100.000',
                                                                                 'Acima de  500.000' => 'Até 500.000',),

                                                                                 'empty' => 'Selecione')); ?>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Validade:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('validade', array('label' => FALSE, 'type' => 'text')); ?>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Ok', array('class' =>'btn btn-success pull-left', 'div' => false)); ?>
                </div>
```

The field "Alçada" and "Validade" appears correctly. But the tag `<form>` just appears in the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not ending the form.

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
            'id' => 'your-form-'.$i, //that $i is the index of the foreach, for example
            'url' => array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => 'aprovar', $procuracao['Attorney']['id']), 'id' => $procuracao['Attorney']['id']
            ));
//all inputs and other stuff
echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>'Ok', 'class' =>'btn btn-success pull-left', 'div' => false));
```

all that inside the `foreach` you're using.

[Here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_end) is the reference of that function in the docs. But basically, it does this

> Closes an HTML form, cleans up values set by FormHelper::create(), and
>   writes hidden input fields where appropriate

Comment: Hi!!! Doesn't work. The form on the first element its fine!! But in the rest doesn't appear the `<form>`

Comment: Probably a clash of names or ids. FormHelper will give the same id to those forms, so you will need to prevent that passing a variable id for that. I will update the answer, but have this in mind: how will you know which form was submitted if all will have the same model? every form submit will be set in `$this->request->data['Model']` in the controller, so the foreach will be useless, no? Also, forms in the same view will lead to the [multiple form validation problem`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669857/multiple-form-with-same-model-name-on-single-page-cakephp/17495130#17495130)

Comment: i tried to change the id and the name of every form but doesn't work also